# Audio not working when incoming call is answered during screen is locked - swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession, linphone, callkit

I am buidling an app using VOIP service. Now i integrated my app with `CallKit` in order to handle incoming call request.

When the app stays in foreground or background they are working fine when answered call. But the problem is that when the screen is locked and i tried to answer the call but unfortunately I can't hear audio for both side even i unlocked the screen.

How to solve this issue?

This is how incoming call reports:

```
func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, handle: String, hasVideo: Bool = false, completion: ((NSError?) -> Void)?) {
    // 1.
    print("This is UUID === ", uuid)
    configureAudioSession()
    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)
    update.hasVideo = hasVideo


    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { error in


        if error == nil {
            // 3.
            self.configureAudioSession()
            let call = CallKitCallInit(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
            self.callKitManager.add(call: call)
            lastCallUUID = uuid
            print("UUID === ", uuid)
        } else {

        }

        // 4.
        completion?(error as NSError?)
    }


}
```

This is how i set audio

```
func configureAudioSession() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)

    } catch {
        print("========== Error in setting category \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
    } catch {
        print("========= Error in setting mode \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
    } catch {
        print("======== Error setting rate \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
    } catch {
        print("======== Error IOBufferDuration \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("========== Error starting session \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

When i answered the call when screen is locked i could see that the error that it throwed in `configureAudioSession()` function.

Why it not able to set audio when the screen is locked?

Comment: Any success in that?

Comment: @WorieN I did by adding `action.fulfill()` inside `provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction)`  CXProviderDelegate function

Comment: @WorieN Check my answer below for more detail. This is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did by adding these lines of code

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    // 1.
    guard let call = callKitManager.callWithUUID(uuid: action.callUUID) else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }
    // 2.
    configureAudioSession()
    // 3.
    call.answer()
    // 4.
    action.fulfill()
}
```

This is `configureAudioSession`

```
func configureAudioSession() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord,
                                mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat,
                                 options: [])

    } catch {
        print("========== Error in setting category \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    do {
        try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
    } catch {
        print("======== Error setting rate \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
    } catch {
        print("======== Error IOBufferDuration \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    do {
        try session.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("========== Error starting session \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat instead of AVAudioSessionModeMoviePlayback mode while configuring audio session.

Comment: I have updated but still not work. Is there any other solution? @Sanjan